# Swift : "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts" error / swift 5

Tags: swift

Following code would show that "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts"

```
if let postDictionary = jsonDictionary["post"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

```
class FeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "single_post", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try(NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe))

                let jsonDictionary = try(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers))

                if let postDictionary = jsonDictionary["post"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let post = Post()
                post.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(postDictionary)
                    self.posts = [post]
                }

                print(jsonDictionary)
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
        }
```

Comment: `let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]`

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Value+of+type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscripts) before posting. This has been covered many times before.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonObject(with:options:)` returns `Any`.

You need to cast it to `[String: AnyObject]` type first.

Change:

```
if let postDictionary = jsonDictionary["post"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

To:

```
if let dictionary = jsonDictionary as? [String: AnyObject], let postDictionary = dictionary["post"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject